# Multiparameter in shell script

Tags: shell

So, I have a simple script whose only purpose is to help me in my lazyness by allowing me to type less thing when setting acl for someone using blih

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" "$2" ]; then
   ~/.blih.py -u X.X@X.eu repository setacl "$1" "$2" rw
fi
```

I've named it *setacl.sh* and set it as an aliases in my *.bash_aliases*

```
alias setacl='~/.bash_scripts/setacl.sh'
```

and yet when I use it, I get the following

```
setacl Java_epicture_2017 X
/root/.bash_scripts/setacl.sh: 3: [: Java_epicture_2017: unexpected operator
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to verify that both arguments are set, write:

```
if [ -n "$1" ] && [ -n "$2" ]
```

Or more simply, check the number of arguments passed:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]
```